# HoloLens-spatial mapping

Tags: hololens, mrtk

When I use HoloLens1 to test the spatial mapping program provided by Microsoft, the program can be successfully build and deployed on the viusal studio, but when I enter my HoloLens ip address into the edge (chrome kernel) browser, the results displayed are as follows Picture, there is no option to download the scanned 3d model provided by the official display ， After I installed the new certificate as instructed, the result did not change, but the same browser interface was displayed [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZzvf.png)

Comment: So, have you gotten into the device portal page?The image you provided is a screenshot from our course video, but the picture attached shows you tripped over the security certificate.

Comment: After I installed the security certificate provided by the web page according to the instructions, the page shown in the picture is still displayed after entering my hololens ip address in the browser

Comment: Thanks for your help， yes I use wifi to connect my hololens1 to my pc, but my device portal page has something wrong there , I have upgrate my question， please look the new picture.

Comment: As you can see, on my web page, there are no options for me to operate, no home button, no 3d view button and so on.

Comment: It is recommended to re-pair your HoloLens with PC by the following steps.  Unpair all devices in Setting from your HoloLens and restart your device. After the device starts, deploy your project to your device, you will be prompted for a PIN to pair your device again. If the issue still happened for you, please open a support ticket through this link: http://aka.ms/hololenssupport so that we can diagnose it deeper for you.

Comment: For HoloLens1, we recommend connecting to your PC using WiFi, and we have documentation on accessing Device Portal updates to bring to your attention:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/using-the-windows-device-portal#setting-up-hololens-to-use-windows-device-portal